# Swift Errors: Braced Block of Statements is an unused closure

Tags: ios, swift

Here's my Code (2 errors):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //ERROR HERE - "Expected type after as"
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

    //Create and configure the scene
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    scene.tick = didTick

    swiftris = Swiftris()
    swiftris.beginGame()

    //Present the scene
    skView.presentScene(scene)

    //ERROR HERE - Braced block of statements is an unused closure
        scene.addPreviewShapeToScene(swiftris.nextShape!){
        self.swiftris.nextShape?.moveTo(StartingColumn, row: StartingRow)
        self.scene.movePreviewShape(self.swiftris.nextShape!){
            let nextShapes = self.swiftris.newShape()
            self.scene.startTicking()
            self.scene.addPreviewShapeToScene(nextShapes.nextShape!) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Don't have a clue what's wrong guys, please help!. 
I'm new to Swift and I'm following the code posted by Bloc.io
It's an intro tutorial to create a game like Tetris - Swiftris. Tutorial Link: 
https://www.bloc.io/tutorials/swiftris-build-your-first-ios-game-with-swift#!/chapters/684

Comment: here's an easy answer, look at this: https://github.com/Bloc/swiftris

Comment: Thanks @Larcerax
I used the updated code but even the the first error persists. "Expected type after as"

Comment: *but even then the first error persists.

Comment: It's running perfectly for me, Rishi, that's where perhaps your version of Xcode or whatever may be the problem, what version are you using?

Comment: I'm running the most UP TO DATE verions of xcode with the most up to date version of IOS, not beta, but the most up to date release of both

Comment: Thanks for trying @Larcerax . My Xcode version's 6.2 - which isn't the latest but it's quite new I think. I'll update to version 7 and try writing it all out again. Cheers.

Comment: I'd just update to the version 6.4, that's the most up to date right now, 7 is still in beta

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Things to look for:

- Do you have the class "SKView" in your project?
- if it is part of a framework, are you importing that framework?

The second error is probably because of the SKView error.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Not sure, please check out the source code github.com/Bloc/swiftris . I'm new to Xcode and Swift sorry.

Comment: Both. Just copied off the tutorial. :)

Comment: ok I'm not getting the crash you're talking about though. It looks like that was the tutorial's git repo that you sent me to. I won't know for sure what your issue is unless I see your code. But try adding the framework "SpriteKit" (project -> Target -> General -> "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" -> "+" at the bottom -> find SpriteKit). Clean, build, try to run again